# Полиморфные связи в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть, скажем, таблица `Attachments` со столбцами: `id | ownerId | ownerType`, которые, соответственно: первичный ключ, внешний ключ и таблица, к которой относится внешний ключ.

Например:

```
  id  |  ownerId  |  ownerType  
---------------------------------
  1        1           Post
  2        1          Comment
```

Можно ли средствами EntityFramework организовать связь так, чтобы на выходе в сущности поста и комментария были коллекции с их вложениями? Что-то вроде:

```
builder.Entity<Post>().
    .HasMany(p => p.Attachments)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.OwnerId); // and a.OwnerType = "Post"
```

---

**UPD:** В комментариях посоветовали просто добавить свойство коллекции вложений в нужные сущности и доверить остальное самой EF. Я так и сделал.

А потом мне захотелось добавить третью сущность с вложениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выглядит ли подобное решение немного странным? Аж 3 внешних ключа.

Comment: EntityFramework не поддерживает такой возможности хотя бы потому, что c#- строго типизированный язык. Какой тип вы ожидаете в данном случае будет у связанного объекта?

Comment: @Anamnian, так тут ведь просто помимо условия совпадения внешнего ключа добавляется условие фильтра по таблице. Причём тут проблема типизации? Можно было бы создать две абсолютно идентичные таблицы вложений (одну для постов, другую для комментариев) и оставить только `OwnerId`, просто не уверен, что плодить две одинаковые таблицы это правильный выход =/

Comment: `Post` и `Comment` имеют общего предка?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я читал про TPH, но у `Post` и `Comment` довольно много различающихся полей

Comment: Почему не сделать просто в `Post` и `Comment` коллекции с `Attachment`, а реализацию этого поручить EF? Пытаетесь сэкономить на спичках?

Comment: @АндрейNOP и без явного указания каких-то связей EF сам обеспечит меня дополнительной таблицей и связями?

Comment: У вас же Code-First, он должен сам построить модель и бд.

Comment: @Anamnian, хм.. тогда удалю `Attachments` из контекста БД и попробую инициировать миграцию и посмотрю...

Comment: Конечно. Как правильно замечают выше, вам не нужно думать об имплементации в БД при Code First (пока явно не столкнетесь с проблемами производительности)

Comment: Ну и ваш вариант будет медленнее работать чем вариант с отдельными таблицами для связи с Post и с Comment скорее всего.

Comment: @АндрейNOP обновил вопрос

Comment: @Anamnian обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну пока, вроде, не сильно плохо выглядит.

Comment: @MrModest Вы хотите сделать вложения для поста, комментария, или приватного сообщения? Лучше сделать так- 2 поля идентификатора, первое указывает на тип объекта (комментарий, пост и т.д.), второе является id в соответствующей таблицу. Обратите внимание- в этом случае поля не являются внешними ключами, и вам нужно будет разработать методы бизнес-логики чтобы получать нужные вложения. Зато решается проблема с последующим подключением вложений к другим типам объектов.

Comment: @Anamnian вы только что описали полиморфную связь, о которой говорится в вопросе. Просто в моём примере в качестве второго id выступает имя таблицы)

Comment: @MrModest Разница в том что у вас изначально было 2 сущности, и не было оговорки что код может расширятся, и вам потребуется вложения для других сущностей.